# Laravel Redirect All Requests To NON-HTTPS

Tags: php, ssl, laravel

There are lots of questions asking how to make a Laravel request HTTPS, but how do you make it **NON** **HTTPS**.  I'd like to make sure all the pages that are not the order page, are not SSL. Basically the opposite of Redirect::secure.

```
    //in a filter

    if( Request::path() != ORDER_PAGE && Request::secure()){
    //do the opposite of this:
    return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }
```

Comment: This may be late, but It might help future visitors. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26875905/1903366)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with a filter that I map to all routes I need to make non SSL

```
Route::filter('prevent.ssl', function () {
    if (Request::secure()) {
        return Redirect::to(Request::getRequestUri(), 302, array(), false);
    }
});
```

Example for a route with non SSL only

```
Route::get('/your_no_ssl_url', array(
    'before' => 'prevent.ssl',
    'uses'   => 'yourController@method',
));
```

If you open `https://example.app/your_no_ssl_url` you will be redirected to `http://example.app/your_no_ssl_url`

Answer (score 1):

try this 
 //in a filter

```
if( Request::path() != ORDER_PAGE && Request::secure()){
//do the opposite of this:
return Redirect::to(Request::path());
}
```

May be this will help you.

Comment: Thx for the response. However I tried it and it still redirects to https.  And it creates a redirect loop.