# Laravel redirect HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to detect and redirect ALL HTTPS requests to HTTP in LARAVEL(coding) level? I am asking because I haven't came across any questions like this, they were all asking to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Redirect All Requests To NON-HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988557/laravel-redirect-all-requests-to-non-https)

Comment: @shukshin.ivan is there an easier way to redirect ALL https requests to http?

Comment: yep, just configure your nginx

Comment: @shukshin.ivan at laravel level though

Comment: check answers, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple middleware for that.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Nonsec
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->secure()) {
            return redirect($request->path());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Add it in a list of `web` array at `middlewareGroups`. File `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Answer (score -1):

Just simple, to add your https link in your link.

For example will be looks like this

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_KEY=base64:R4pkmCx5jr21J3EgsvYttiJdBsnIpC3rli0fCfxcd0c=
APP_URL=https://linkkamu.com/
```

i hope i will help your problem.

Comment: `APP_URL` is for console usage only. Web requests are aware of the host and scheme.