# Force redirection from http to https laravel 5.4 heroku

Tags: php, laravel, http, heroku, https

Forcing to redirect URI from http to https using Laravel 5.4 on Heroku

Method I used to solve this problem:

APP_URL: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/45891292/6607216`

MiddleWare: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/45858789/6607216`

Proxies: `https://gist.github.com/ilhamsj/819369a56bb983eac018c5f4e04cda50`

I tried to upgrade Laravel version to 5.6 and 5.8 but no luck also.

Kind of wondering if Heroku is blocking something to privent redirect from http to https. because locally, it's redirecting to https.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28403907/6212294)?

Comment: Yes, This is a middleware solution I listed on on the solutions I tried.